# Making a global nav for a fixed Epub

Tags: epub

I am making a fixed EPub. I want to make a global nav (rather than one that exists on a page at the beginning of the book).

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you consider a "global nav".

Comment: A collapsible nav that either lives on the top or the side of the user interface and can be accessed at all times. Rather than creating an internal TOC that sits on page two of a book.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a [fixed layout](http://www.idpf.org/epub/fxl/) epub, you'll have to create an epub3 book, which requires a [NAV document](https://idpf.github.io/a11y-guidelines/content/nav/toc.html). Note that very few epub apps and devices support fixed layout epubs.

If you're creating this book for yourself, also check out the [cbz format](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-cbrcbz-files-distribute-comic-strip-graphic/).